# Почему в Python можно не описывать поля классов, а в C# обязательно?

Tags: python, c#, ооп

Вот я создаю экземпляр класса `acac=Automobile()`, неважно какого класса. Почему в Python, в отличие от того же Cs, я могу написать `acac.bgg=77`, и потом вывести `acac.bgg`, и Python не выдаст ошибку, учитывая то, что bgg я нигде не создавал, а придумал просто так?

[image: Код и консоль. В консоли выводится 77, а не ошибка.]

Почему в Python можно не описывать поля классов, а в C# обязательно?

Comment: Потому что C# строго типизирован.

Comment: @aepot , скорее потому, что C# статически типизирован

Comment: не совсем. просто так задуманы возможности языка. И все. Никто не мешает сделать типизированным, но при этом дать возможность добавлять произвольно "поля" и наоборот - список полей должен быть задан строго, а типы произвольные.

Comment: На самом деле в python можно не только задавать таким образом поля классов но и поля функций как бы странно это не звучало.